# Is there a way to set Excel up so it will skip over the cells containing formulas and jump right to the cells requiring direct data entries?

Tags: worksheet-function, cells, ignore

I have a sheet with multiple columns that I need to enter numerical data in certain cells. Some of the rows contains formulas for totals and percentage results.

Is there a way as I enter data and arrow down to the next cell that it automatically skips the cells containing formulas and goes right to the next cells needing direct data entries?

Comment: Unlock the cells that you want to be able to select, using cell properties.  The protect the sheet and make sure the Select locked cells is not chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. unprotect the worksheet
2. unlock all cells
3. lock all formula cells
4. protect the worksheet

In step **4**, set the protection such that only unlocked cells *(data cells)* can be Selected.